# Фильтрация с оператором ИЛИ по разным полям

Tags: moysklad-json-api

Можно ли в апи осуществить поиск контрагента по двум полям email или телефон одним запросом?

Comment: В каком именно апи?

Comment: @rvs судя по метке moysklad-json-api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да. Используйте фильтр search, котоырй ищет одновременно по нескольким полям

> curl -X GET \
>     'https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/entity/counterparty?search=350143' \
>     -H 'Authorization: Basic '

Документация по использованию филтра search https://online.moysklad.ru/api/remap/1.1/doc/index.html#%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужно найти контрагентов, у которых email = xxx@xxx.xx или телефон = xxxxxxxxxx